# Applying synsets to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like such a simple question but I'd like to avoid looping if possible. I have the following data set in a panda column:

```
df['token']:
0     [If, you, can, only, visit, one, museum, in, N...
1     [Do, n't, let, the, neighborhood, ,, exterior,...
2     [Momofuku, Milk, Bar, is, one, of, those, plac...
3     [Have, you, been, here, ?, Tell, us, about, it...
4     [Add, the, Palmer, Trading, Company, to, your,...
5     [Porchetta, is, fast, and, simple, food, ., No...
```

Name: token, dtype: object

I'd like to apply wordnet wordnet.synsets functional to each value in the list ( if, you, can etc) and only use the first result given back for example:

```
 exterior [Synset('outside.n.01'), Synset('outside.n.02'), Synset('exterior.a.01')]
```

I'd like to be able to use apply to use only the first result: Synset('outside.n.01')

Comment: I'm a little confused, if you're only using the first result, is there any need to run the function on any of the others?  I.e. could you apply a function that calls `Synset` on just the first element of a list?

Comment: I'm not an expert regarding nltk or wordnet but I believe you can only pass an individual word to the function and that returns a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, I think what you are looking for is a way to replace each of the words with the first result from calling `synsets` on the word, Is that correct?  You just need a function that wraps synsets that accepts a list of words, and returns the first element of what synset returns for each one of those:

```
def first(wordlist):
    # wordlist is a list of words, i.e. ['sun', 'shine', 'spotless']
    return [synsets(word)[0] for word in wordlist]
```

Then use applymap to run it on each element of the DataFrame:

```
df.applymap(first)
```

Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is it possible to pass watch two Pandas columns to applymap?

Comment: I think I found the answer to that too  df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda row: my_test(row['a'], row['c']), axis=1)

Comment: To pass two columns, you could do df[['col1', 'col2']].applymap(...)