# Returning Synset('') wrapper when using DataFrame.apply() to generate values

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

When I pass a function via DataFrame.apply() I'm getting values wrapped in what I assume is their object type. I've seen this error for two applications now: one using NLTK's Wordnet library (returns Synset('value'), and the other with Datetime (Datetime('value')).

I've drawn on a number of examples to produce the code below, so I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried to use this function--[Applying synsets to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420216/applying-synsets-to-pandas) (as well as another variation)-- but for some reason it's returning a Series (even though I specified it is a dataframe) and so .applymap() doesn't work. Variations using .map() and simply .apply() were also problematic.

Here's what I have (using pandas and a few nltk libraries):

```
df_agri_clean['Synsets'] = [x[0] for x in df_agri_clean['Category'].apply(wordnet.synsets)]
df_agri_clean
```

Here's the output:

```
    Category        Synsets
0   agricultural    Synset('agricultural.a.01')
1   domestic        Synset('domestic.n.01')
2   animal          Synset('animal.n.01')
3   services        Synset('services.n.01')
5   food            Synset('food.n.01')
```

My desired output would be:

```
    Category        Synsets
0   agricultural    agricultural.a.01
1   domestic        domestic.n.01
2   animal          animal.n.01
3   services        services.n.01
5   food            food.n.01
```

I'll be using a similar structure to build a matrix of lemmas, definitions and hypernyms for a fairly long list of terms across a few different categories, so a scalable solution would be ideal.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding .name() to x[0]. See answer by Alvas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517924/extract-word-from-synset-using-wordnet-in-nltk-3-0).:

```
df_agri_clean['Synsets'] = [x[0].name() for x in df_agri_clean['Category'].apply(wordnet.synsets)]
print(df_agri_clean['Synsets'])
```

Output:

```
    Category        Synsets
0   agricultural    agricultural.a.01
1   domestic        domestic.n.01
2   animal          animal.n.01
3   services        services.n.01
5   food            food.n.01
```